# Google Admin SDK: How to modify the feature instances of a Calendar Resource

Tags: google-admin-sdk

Source: https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/resources/calendars

When fetching a resource calendar the structure of `featureInstances` is defined as list of objects but this is not marked as writable. Instead there is a writable property of the same name defined as a string with description "Instances of features for the calendar resource."

What is the format of this string?

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the documentation for the  [`Resources.features`](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/resources/features) object. And you can insert this feature through [this endpoint](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/resources/features/insert).

**So what is the difference between the string and the array of objects?**

Basically it would depend on the number of features, if you only have one it will be there just as an string, and if you have multiple features, then the field is a list of objects containing all different features.

From [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/resources/calendars):

> `featureInstances`    **string**  Instances of features for the calendar resources.
>
> `featureInstances[].feature`   **nested object**   The feature that this is an instance of. A calendar resource may have multiple instances of a feature.

Answer (score 0):

The payload for [API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/resources.calendars/insert) should be an Array<{ feature: { name: string } }:

```
 "featureInstances": [
    {
      "feature": {
        "name": "Projector"
      }
    },
    {
      "feature": {
        "name": "Jamboard"
      }
    }
  ]
```